# How to loop to create and display multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I want to create a relative frequency summary for a set of variables I specify from a given data frame. I have:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(psych)

mtcars %>%
    count(mpg) %>%
    mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
    arrange(desc(n)) %>%
    headTail(top = 5, bottom = 5)

mtcars %>%
    count(disp) %>%
    mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
    arrange(desc(n)) %>%
    headTail(top = 5, bottom = 5)
```

This displays each of the data frames, which is what I want:
[image]

How can I create a loop so that I can specify a list of variables and create the multiple data frames from it. For example:

```
my_variables <- c(mpg, dipl)

# some function to make multiple data frames
```

If there is an all-together different way to achieve this please answer with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to loop over variables and make the frequency table like above for each?  If so, the code below would do.  In short, `count_` function can take character variable name, while `count` takes "naked" variable name.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(psych)

make_freq_data <- function(name) {
  mtcars %>%
    count_(name) %>%
    mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
    arrange(desc(n)) %>%
    headTail(top = 5, bottom = 5)
}

my_variables <- c("mpg", "disp")
lapply(my_variables, make_freq_data)
```